# Entity Framework and working with users

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I site up using the default authentication that does standard in the visual studio 2015 default project.  I registered a user, checked that I could login, logoff etc and all was fine.

However I then changed a field in one of my classes from something else to applicationUser and this required a database update.  After the update my user was still in the database but will not return via ApplicationDbContext.  Each new user I create is fine, but the first exists in the database only.

After I create a few more users I tried updating the password of one via ApplicationDbContext.Users and this saw that user disappear from results but not the database also.

So I have two questions, why did this occur and what is the correct method for updating things like user passwords, email etc?

For some example code:

```
user = await store.FindByNameAsync("kidshibuya@gmail.com");
DB.Users.ToList()
```

Neither of the above return the user of that email (username is the email) but it absolutely IS in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For changing password in asp.net identity use this code:

```
ApplicationUser user = await store.FindByIdAsync(userId);
await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(user, hashedpwd);
await store.UpdateAsync(user);
```